# Application name is not displayed as per the Current Language in "Manage Applications" on Android 2.X devices

Tags: android, internationalization

After changing the Language, Home screen displays the proper current language specific Application name but Settings->Manage Applications is not able to display Application with internationalized application name.

On re-starting the Phone it displays it as expected.

The issue is observed on Sony Experia which has Android 2.3.3 and Samsung Galaxy which has Android 2.3.6. It is working as expected on Android 4.0 onwards.

Has anyone faced the similar problem?

Comment: It works for me on Galaxy with 2.3. How did you define your title for different languages.

Comment: I configured it like android:label="@string/appName under AndroidManifest.xml where different mapping for appName is configured under strings.xml as per the locale. Note that it displays proper application name on Home Screen but not in the "Manage Applications".

Comment: And do you have strings.xml in /res/values folders for your languages?

Comment: I also observed that other applications provided by Android also has the same problem. For example after changing the Language from English to Japanese, Home screen displays Browser application name in Japanese but "Manage Application" still displays it in English.

Comment: Yes, I have strings.xml in /res/values folder for languages.

Comment: Sorry, I double checked, I have the same behaviour :(

Comment: oh.. I think there is a problem in Android 2.x version. I tried to search a specific bug for it but didn't find anything.

Comment: When I went to the home screen and again to App Manager, it was fine.

Comment: have u tried with rebooting of device? Admittedly, this is not the proper way, but you should try this once.